# Can't save files to different directory

Tags: python

My script works to save the files to the same directory as the code.  I want to save it somewhere else.  I've verified the directory exists.  I know this has been asked many times, but I feel like I'm doing what others have said and I'm still getting `IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:`

```
    filepath = os.path.join('/Dropbox/music_files', new_filename)
    f = open(filepath, 'w+')
    f.write(content)
    f.close()
```

Comment: are you certain that your Dropbox directory is in the root of your filesystem?

Comment: Does this return true os.path.exists(path)  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### make sure that `/Dropbox/music_files` exists

If not, use `os.makedirs('/Dropbox/music_files')` to create the dir you want to save into

Also, context manager is always better.

```
import os

if not os.path.exists('/Dropbox/music_files'):
    os.makedirs('/Dropbox/music_files')

filepath = os.path.join('/Dropbox/music_files', new_filename)

with open(filepath, 'w+') as f:
    f.write(content)
```